# Capture CTRL+A in a SmartGWT listgrid

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, smartgwt

I develop a SmartGWT web app were I have a ListGrid. The user can select every record in the listgrid by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but sometimes when I try in Internet Explorer (11) I get the following warning:

> WARN:Log:Trying to derive keyName from the charsetValueToKeyNameMap: 1 = 'undefined'

I want to improve my <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> function so if the user has selected everything in the listgrid and then presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> again, another function will fire. This works perfectly in Chrome but never works in IE as the warning above shows up all the time after the the first <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> has been caught.

This is the (slightly modified) code which handles the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. As I said, this works perfectly in Chrome but not in IE. I guess it's maybe a SmartGWT/IE bug but maybe someone has an idea of a workaround?

```
    listgrid.addKeyPressHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.KeyPressHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.events.KeyPressEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyName().toLowerCase().equals("a") && event.isCtrlKeyDown()) {
                event.cancel();
                if (listgrid.getSelectedRecords().length != 0 && listgrid.getSelectedRecords().length == listgridRecordList.getLength()) {
                    //we have pressed Ctrl+A two times in a row and want to the ctrl+a_twice_function
                    DO_CTRl+A_TWICE_FUNCTION();
                }
                else
                    listgrid.selectAllRecords();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try using onKeyDown instead of keyPress. To get the key pressed with onKeyDown its like this  String key =  com.smartgwt.client.util.EventHandler.getKey();

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried that but unfortunately I got the same result..

Comment: No prob, another idea is to move the keypressHandler from the listgrid to the layout containing the listgrid.

Comment: It did actually work better! Or, I get the same result if the listgrid has the focus but if a click outside the lisgrid and then press Ctrl+A twice I will not get the warning mentioned above. I guess it is some kind of bug in SmartGWT but I can use this solution for now. Thanks!